# VBA lock a single cell in current code

Tags: excel, vba

I hope you can help and thanks in advance. I have a following code and I like to add a code that freeze/locked cell `$H$3`. Please help.

```
Sub Copy_Tabs_New()
Dim x, ListItem As Variant
Dim numtimes As Byte
x = InputBox("Enter number of times to copy 4075 Wilson")
If Not IsNumeric(x) Then Exit Sub
If (x < 1) Or (x > 55) Then Exit Sub
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("4075 Wilson").Select
ListItem = Range("C3").Value
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For numtimes = 1 To x
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("4075 Wilson").Copy After:=ActiveSheet
    Range("H3").Value = ListItem
    Range("C3").Value = Range("B2").Value
    ListItem = Range("C3").Value
Next
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("4075 Wilson").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub Copy_Tabs_New()
    Dim x, ListItem As Variant
    Dim numtimes As Byte

    x = InputBox("Enter number of times to copy 4075 Wilson")
    If Not IsNumeric(x) Then Exit Sub
    If (x < 1) Or (x > 55) Then Exit Sub
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("4075 Wilson").Select
    ListItem = Range("C3").Value
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For numtimes = 1 To x
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("4075 Wilson").Copy After:=ActiveSheet
        Range("H3").Value = ListItem
        Call freeeze
        Range("C3").Value = Range("B2").Value
        ListItem = Range("C3").Value
    Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("4075 Wilson").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub freeeze()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Unprotect
        .Cells.Locked = False
        .Range("H3").Locked = True
        .Protect
    End With
End Sub
```